# Force HTTPS along with removing file extension

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been trying to force HTTPS along with removing the php extensions but I always get a redirect loop on the browser when I mix them both.

I searched around Stackoverflow but there were only things about one in specific and not both.

This is what I currently have:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule . https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Why do you have `RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80`? This means that the rule will only work if its non-HTTPS; is that a typo?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid My bad, that part was a typo. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what i use to get around this;

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
Options +Indexes
AcceptPathInfo Off
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase   /

ErrorDocument 404 http://mysite.co.uk/404page/404.html

#Force from http to https
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mysite.co.uk$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mysite.co.uk/$1 [R=301]

#take off index.html
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*/)index\.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule . http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%1 [R=301,NE,L]

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]    

## hide .html extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.html to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

@Switchfire - Working for redirection! thanks a lot. But giving some error if you have hash (#) in url.

So I made a few changes. and also make it to
1. prevent direct access to directory
2. redirect both www or non-www request to https://www

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
Options -Indexes
AcceptPathInfo Off
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase   /

#Force from http to https
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```